# Enabled firewall and rebooted. Now unable to SSH

Tags: ssh

In enabled my pi‘s firewall with `ufw enable` and rebooted the pi itself.
Now I’m not able to login via ssh anymore. Since it’s a headless Raspbian, I can’t connect it to a display either.
Is there another way to reach it than setup from scratch?

Comment: Just connect display and keyboard and you should be able to log in...

Comment: What Dirk means (in case it is not clear) is that if it is headless because you do not have a display and keyboard you can use, life is hard.  However, if it is "headless" in the sense that you installed the lite version and have never plugged a display in, do not despair: There's a text based console login that runs by default.  You may have to boot with the display attached to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done the following myself, but I'm fairly confident this will work (it won't hurt)

- take the SD card out and put it in another computer
- edit `cmdline.txt` (careful which editor you use)
- add `init=/boot/fixufw.sh` to the end of the line
- create `fixufw.sh` file in the boot partition,

```
#!/bin/sh
ufw disable
shutdown
```

or even

```
#!/bin/sh
ufw limit from any to any app SSH
shutdown
```

- put the SD card into the pi and boot
- wait a few moments until the pi has booted and shut down
- edit the SD card to remove the text you added
- put the card in the pi and boot

Answer (score 0):

@Jaromanda Xs answer did not work for me, maybe because `ufw` has not been loaded yet at this stage or the changes are not written. I could clearly see that `ufw` was still blocking my `ssh` requests when I looked into `rootfs/var/log/syslog`.

However, I was able to edit `/etc/rc.local` with the line `sudo ufw disable`. You add the line before the `exit 0` of course.

This way you don't have to take the card out and undo the changes - you can simply do it on the live system.

Answer (score 0):

I can not comment yet.  I've followed @bomben advice but decided to put this line in rc.local:

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
```

Then I logged in successfully.

**Remember** After successfully login, remove this line from rc.local
(ufw is now permanently modified)

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have physical access to it ... bad news
If you have access but you don't have mouse/monitor/keyboard you can always take the microSD out of it, mount root partition, edit ufw config file and done

Comment: "mount root partition" where?

Comment: if you have an access to this microSD you can mount it on any other Linux machine, or, use other microSD card with Linux to boot your raspberry, and, using usb->microSD interface, enter your microSD, and mount it on the raspberry

Comment: that's the sort of detail you'd want in the answer ... not just "mount it" :p